# Setting shared_buffers in postgresql.conf does not seem to take effect

Tags: postgresql, configuration, performance, performance-tuning

We're on CentOS release 6.6, PostgreSQL version 8.4.20. (Yes, this is not bleeding edge.)

In `postgresql.conf`, we have:

```
shared_buffers = 4096MB
```

kernel shm values are set nice and high:

```
[root@green data]# sysctl -a | grep shm
kernel.shmmax = 15922077696
kernel.shmall = 3887226
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
```

We have plenty of memory:

```
[root@green data]# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      31097812   30474972     622840    2873672    1961088   20565360
-/+ buffers/cache:    7948524   23149288
Swap:      1959920      93852    1866068
```

Yet the value for `shared_buffers` reported by `pg_settings` is only 512MB, not the 4GB set in `postgresql.conf`:

```
postgres=# select name, setting, min_val, max_val, context from  
pg_settings where name='shared_buffers';
      name      | setting | min_val |  max_val   |  context   
----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------
 shared_buffers | 524288  | 16      | 1073741823 | postmaster
```

Yes, we've done a full restart, and `SHOW config_file` confirms that I've edited the right `postgresql.conf`.

My very great thanks to anyone who can provide insight into this mystery.

Answer (score 18):

The canonical unit for `shared_buffers` is pages of `8kB`, so the actual memory allocated in bytes is:

`524288` * `8192` = `4294967296` or `4096*1024*1024` as requested.

You can also check the size of the segment of memory with `ipcs -m`

Comment: [qalc](https://qalculate.github.io/) is a nice tool to deal with this conversions
**Command:** `qalc 524288*8 kibibytes to mebibytes`, **Return:**
`524288 * (8 * kibibyte) = 4096 mebibytes`

Answer (score 9):

What [@Daniel explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103778/3684) so accurately becomes rather obvious when you add the respective column to your query:

```
SELECT name, setting, unit, min_val, max_val, context
FROM   pg_settings WHERE name = 'shared_buffers';
```

Or just:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'shared_buffers';
```

Consider the [project guidelines](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for your "non-bleeding-edge" (a.k.a. outdated and unsupported) Postgres version.

Answer (score 1):

got the same issue and when I ran the following query:

```
select * from pg_settings
```

I got sourcefile pointing to postgresql.auto.conf, so removed the file as only shared_buffers value was set in the file and restarted

```
select *  from pg_settings where name='shared_buffers';

-[ RECORD 1 ]---+-------------------------------------------------------------
name            | shared_buffers
sourcefile      | /u02/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```